# How can I just kill the stuck job but not kill the application in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

[image]

As above, I just want to kill the stage 1244, not kill the application.
if I click the `kill` button, is it kill the whole application ?
and how can I do to kill just the job in the application that I want to kill ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kill button that you highlighted will kill the current job. However:

- If this is an interactive Spark session (i.e running Jupyter notebook or `spark-shell` or `pyspark`) then the application will still alive.
- If this is an non-interactive Spark session (i.e `spark-submit`) then the application will get killed together with the job, because the application status is considered as failed.

Comment: Please help me here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68078584/is-there-way-that-we-can-get-the-id-of-partition-which-the-current-row-processed  , thanks very much !