# How to get the partitionId or taskContext of Spark in hive UDF when SQL executed with Spark engine?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

For example, we execute the SQL below with Spark engine, we need `my_udf(row)`
return the partition id in Spark.

```
add jar hdfs:///dir/udf/udf.jar; 
create temporary function my_udf as 'com.my.MyUDF';

select row, my_udf(row) from table;
```

I have known how to get taskId in Hive UDF executed in MR engine: [How to get the taskID or mapperID(something like partitionID in Spark) in a hive UDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68079180/how-to-get-the-taskid-or-mapperidsomething-like-partitionid-in-spark-in-a-hive)  , but it does not effective when executed in Spark engine. Please tell me how to get partitionID or taskContext of Spark in Hive UDF, thanks very much !

Comment: A UDF doesn't have access to the internals of Spark.

You can use the `spark_partition_id` function if your data is in a Dataset though.

Comment: @kanielc you mean there is no way to get Spark taskContext in a Hive UDF ?

Comment: I have got the correct answer on my own, just look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68079180/how-to-get-the-taskid-or-mapperidsomething-like-partitionid-in-spark-in-a-hive/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the correct answer on my own, just look here : [How to get the taskID or mapperID(something like partitionID in Spark) in a hive UDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68079180/how-to-get-the-taskid-or-mapperidsomething-like-partitionid-in-spark-in-a-hive/)

This answer above will introduce you the follow tips:

1. how to get taskId in Hive UDF with MR execution engine;
2. how to get taskContext and partitionId in Hive UDF with Spark execution engine.

Hope it works for you !

Answer (score 0):

This may be able to do what you want (sample UDF below)

```scala
import org.apache.spark.TaskContext

val foo = udf  { (x: Int) => TaskContext.getPartitionId }
```

The `getPartitionId` function should get the information you need.

Comment: Thanks for answer,  but this is not what I need. I want to get the Spark partitionID or 
 taskContext in a Hive UDF.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68079180/how-to-get-the-taskid-or-mapperidsomething-like-partitionid-in-spark-in-a-hive/  ， I have found the answer by my own here.